# Bash script to String concat two variables and do File compare

Tags: bash, variables, unix, string-comparison, string-concatenation

what I am trying to achieve is, to delete same filenames(filename+modfiedtimestamp)exisitng in Src_Dir1 and Src_Dir2

So first i have tried to deploy all the filenames to tempa(Src_Dir1) and tempb(Src_Dir2) respectively.

Below is the screenshot of the source directory.

[image: source directory]

Files inside archive be like this and few files outside too..

[image: files inside archive]

So, initially I am want to deal with the files inside Archive(SRC_Dir1) and later outside Archive(SRC_Dir2) what I am trying to do is to use a while loop to read each and every filename and string concat with the modified timestamp(mtime) and input to tempc(like for example it should be like **AirTimeActs_2018-12-03.csv+2019-01-24 14:41:53.000000000 -0500 = AirTimeActs_2018-12-03.csv_2019-01-24 14:41:53.000000000 -0500** this is how it should be generating into **tempc** file for each and every filename inside Archive(SRC_Dir1). This is where I am stuck under string concat variable section on how to proceed. Please help me with the code, hope I am comprehensible.

**IMPORTANT**

(Really appreciate it, if you help me out with the extension of the code which i haven't mentioned here and yet to achieve which is - > 
Have to implement the same code(which I am trying to do for tempa, I'd like to do it for tempb too and name it as tempd) and then do a file data compare between tempc and tempd) if there is any kind of same data filename, then delete the file existing in Src_Dir2, if there is no same data filename, then do nothing.)

```
 #!/bin/bash
    Src_Dir1=path/Airtime_Activation/Archive
    Src_Dir2=path/Airtime_Activation/

    find "$Src_Dir1" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.xlsx" -o -name "*.csv" | sed "s/.*\///" > -print>path/Airtime_Activation/temp_a
    find "$Src_Dir2" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.xlsx" -o -name "*.csv" | sed "s/.*\///" > -print>path/Airtime_Activation/temp_b

    echo 'phase1'
    cat path/Airtime_Activation/temp_a | while read file; 
    do
        echo 'phase1.5'
        echo "$file"
        echo 'phase2'
        mtime=$(stat -c '%y' $file)
        Full_name=${file}_${mtime}
        echo "$Full_name" >> path/Airtime_Activation/temp_c
        echo 'phase3'

    done
```

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net to verify your script.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to achieve. Please [edit] your question and add an example: Which files are in both directories? Which ones do yo want to delete and which ones should be kept? Describe this as text, not (only) as a screenshot. Please explain what you expect to get in `temp_a` etc. when you run the script with the example data.

Comment: @Bodo - i have explained in a more detailed manner, please check it now

Comment: @Jetchisel - i have made the changes in shellcheck.net, and there are no errors but still the code seems to be not working, at the $Full_name >>

Comment: @Jetchisel - Solved! I have changed it to echo "$Full_name" and it worked! Now i need help in the extension of the code

Comment: @Bodo - Now I need help in extension of the code, which is mentioned under "iMPORTANT" section

Comment: check here  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036 on how to compare your files

Comment: @Jetchisel- thank you.. solved , used grep

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
    Src_Dir1=path/Airtime_Activation/Archive
    Src_Dir2=path/Airtime_Activation/

    find "$Src_Dir1" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.xlsx" -o -name "*.csv" | sed "s/.*\///" > -print>path/Airtime_Activation/temp_a
    find "$Src_Dir2" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.xlsx" -o -name "*.csv" | sed "s/.*\///" > -print>path/Airtime_Activation/temp_b

    echo 'phase1'
    cat path/Airtime_Activation/temp_a | while read file; 
    do
        echo 'phase1.5'
        echo "$file"
        echo 'phase2'
        mtime=$(stat -c '%y' $file)
        Full_name=${file}_${mtime}
        echo "$Full_name" >> path/Airtime_Activation/temp_c
        echo 'phase3'

    done

cat /path/Airtime_Activation/temp_b | while read file
#while IFS="" read -r -d $'\0' file; 

do
    #echo "$file"
    echo 'phase2'
    mtime=$(stat -c '%y' $Src_Dir2/$file)
    Full_name=${file}_${mtime}
    echo "$Full_name" >> path/temp_d
    echo 'phase3'

done


#file compare and delete old files from outisde archive
grep -Ff temp_d temp_c > path/Airtime_Activation/temp_e
cat path/Airtime_Activation/temp_e | while read file
#while IFS="" read -r -d $'\0' file; 

do
    #echo "$file"
    echo 'phase2'
    echo "${file%_*}"
    rm $Src_Dir2/${file%_*}
    echo 'phase3'

done
```